# How do I render content from a wp_editor in a plugin setting field?

Tags: plugins, settings-api, wp-editor

I have a plugin setting that uses `wp_editor()` to handle the input and will get echoed as part of a shortcode. Everything is working great on the admin side but when I echo the output on the client side, in the shortcode, the content does not echo with line breaks and paragraph breaks, like `the_content()`.

Is there an existing method (or function) for echoing `wp_editor()` content from other sources, e.g. a plugin setting? Or do I need to parse and build paragraphs and line breaks manually (I feel like I'm reinventing the wheel here!)?

Example code for reference:

```
add_action('admin_init', 'my_plugin_settings');

function my_plugin_settings() {

    add_settings_section(
        'my_messages_section',
        'Messages',
        'Messages',
        'my_settings'
    );

    register_setting('my_settings', 'my_failure_message');

    add_settings_field(
        'my_failure_message',
        'Failure Message',
        'my_failure_message_input',
        'my_settings',
        'my_messages_section'
    );

}

function my_failure_message_input() {
    wp_editor(get_option('my_failure_message'), 'my_failure_message');
}

function my_plugin_shortcodes() {
    add_shortcode('my_shortcode', 'my_messages_shortcode');
}

add_action('init', 'my_plugin_shortcodes');

function my_messages_shortcode($atts = [], $content = NULL, $tag = '') {
    echo get_option('my_failure_message');
}
```

Desired output:

```
<p><strong>Failed.</strong></p>
<p>There was an error. Please try again later.</p>
```

Actual output (that folds into one line):

```
<strong>Failed.</strong>

There was an error. Please try again later.
```

Answer (score 0):

`the_content` [filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_content/) can be used to filter the content after it is retrieved from the database and before it is printed to the screen.
[The Core filters](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.1/src/wp-includes/default-filters.php#L131) on `the_content` are:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wptexturize'        );  
add_filter( 'the_content', 'convert_smilies'    );
add_filter( 'the_content', 'convert_chars'      );
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop'            );
add_filter( 'the_content', 'shortcode_unautop'  );
add_filter( 'the_content', 'prepend_attachment' );
```

Reference to some of above filters:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wptexturize
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/convert_smilies
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop

In general; this should get your job done.

```
function my_messages_shortcode($atts = [], $content = NULL, $tag = '') {
    return apply_filters('the_content', get_option('my_failure_message') );
}
```

Comment: Please **[edit] your answer**, and add an explanation: **why** could that solve the problem?

Comment: The function name is `apply_filters` and not `apply_filter`..

Comment: @SallyCJ Thanks for correction.